# Match two dataframes columnwise and extract values from another column in a particular order

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two `dataframe`s that look like this

```
df1

    fileName    Text
0    file1        A
1    file2        B
2    file3        C
3    file4        D
4    file5        E


df2 

    fileName    Value
0    file3        0
1    file2        1
2    file1        1
3    file5        0
4    file6        1
```

The contents of `df1.fileName` is equal to contents of `df2.fileName` but the order is jumbled in `df2`. I want to extract the value column in the order of `df1.fileName`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If duplicates in `df2['fileName']` then create [`ordered categorical`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html) column, sorting and select `Value`:

```
print (df2)
  fileName  Value
0    file3      0
1    file2      1
2    file1      1
3    file5      0
4    file4      1
5    file1      1
6    file3      1


df2['fileName'] = pd.Categorical(df2['fileName'], categories=df1['fileName'], ordered=True)
out = df2.sort_values('fileName')['Value']
print (out)
2    1
5    1
1    1
0    0
6    1
4    1
3    0
Name: Value, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Is it okay if df2 contains some duplicates but all of df1 ?

Comment: @papabiceps - duplicates are in both DataFrames?

Comment: No df1 has unique values, but df2 has some duplicates. But df2 has all of df1.